# Having issue in implementing effect like facebook right sidebar scroller

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement effect like  facebook right sidebar scroller but if the data changes dynamically then it does not work properly?

Here is my javascript code:-

```
var target = $('.aside');
var div_position = target.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() { 

    var y_position = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(y_position > div_position) {

        target.css('margin-top','-1000px');
        target.css('margin-bottom','30px');

    }
    else {    

        target.css('margin-top','0px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into Scroll Spy?
https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy

I believe it does what you are tying to accomplish